# d3 wait for n second per iteration

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, d3.js, timeout

I'm trying to iterate *synchronously* in d3, and wait for a specific number of seconds per iteration.

```
years = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
          for (iter = 0; iter <= years.length; iter++) {
              setTimeout(function() {
                console.log(iter);
              }, 5000);
          }
```

What I want is it to print 1, then wait 5 seconds, then print 2, then wait 5 seconds, then print 3, etc.

I read [For loop does not work in D3.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38418284/for-loop-does-not-work-in-d3-js) which states that when iterating the program will step to the next iteration's `console.log` statement before finishing the first, so it will perform them all at nearly the same time.

Is there any way to print 1, wait 5 seconds, print 2, wait 5 seconds, print 3, etc. ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The snippet below shows a way to do achieve the wait using a [recursive function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Recursion).

You will remark that `d3` is not used at all in this example - just like shared in the question. In case animations need to be performed every 5 seconds, then using [`d3.timeout`](https://github.com/d3/d3-timer#timeout) instead of `setTimeout` might provide abetter performance.

```js
years = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

function processYear(currentIndex) {

  console.log('processing year', years[currentIndex], ' - currentIndex equals', currentIndex)
  
  if (currentIndex < years.length-1) {
    // schedule processing of following year in 5 seconds
    setTimeout(function() {
      processYear(++currentIndex)
    }, 5000)
  }

}

// process first item of the year array
processYear(0)
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
promise = (val) => new Promise(res => setTimeout(() => {
  console.log(val)
  res()
}, 5000));

(async() => {
  years = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
  for (iter = 0; iter <= years.length; iter++) {
    await promise(iter);
  }
})()
```